# Validate if email address is in the Outlook global address book

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a cell(C4) that users will input their email address. I would like to check if the email address is in the global address book of Outlook.

If existing, name will be output on a cell(C5) - first name and last name combined, if not existing, error message will be thrown.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate Outlook from Excel VBA macro for getting the job done. The [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) article can help you setting everything up and running.

Use the [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method which creates a [Recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object. By using the following sequence of property and method calls you may get a corresponding [ContactItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem) object where you can retrieve all the required for you information:

```
recipient.AddressEntry.GetContact()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference it is quite hard but was able to figure out a way :)

my code was kinda long but what I did was to put on separate modules for getting the data from excel cells first then another module to look up to gab :D